# Lazy minting contract - How to deal with unique (off-chain) metadata

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, mint

Let's say I want to create a digital card collection. I create the metadata and image parts, and then combine them. So now I have a few thousand unique images.

Now I want people to be able to [lazy mint](https://nftschool.dev/how-to/lazy-minting/) them. How would the smart contract look like given that the IPFS metadata and image uri would have to be different for every minted card?

I have an idea on how it would work if I used HTTPS instead, I could just create the links myself and only change some id at the end in the contract, but I'd rather avoid using a central database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to publish folders to IPFS.
So you'll put metadata files for all the NFTs into that folder and receive an IPFS hash. To access individual file use this: `folderIPFSHash/fileName`

In the ERC-721 contract, add the `folderIPFSHash` into `_baseURI` variable, and for each `tokenId` a unique metadata path can be generated by concatenating strings to form: `_baseURI/tokenId.json` as output for the `tokenURI` function.